# Java program for de-duplicating an array

Tags: java, arrays, deduplication

Could someone help with writing an efficient java function for the below please?

Without using internal sorting or deduplication function, take an array which contains duplicate 
entries and return a new array without duplicates. eg

```
deduplicate(array(2,5,10,1, “john" “andy", 5, “peter”, “andy”))
```

> // returns 2,5,10,1,“john”, “andy”, “peter”

Comment: Those are not Java arrays. Javascript?

Comment: You should show us what you have attempted so far, then we can help you move into the right direction.

Comment: Does it have to be in the same relative order?

Comment: to sort an arry convert it into an arraylist    && to remove the duplicates of an array conver it into a "SET"

Comment: @NullSoulException I think that would be considered "using an internal deduplication function"

Comment: Why can't you do the sensible thing and use something that already exists. Homework?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a hash based container such as a `HashMap` and for each element in the array first check if it is present in the container and if not add it. When done return all the elements in the container as an array.

This will be efficient because each check to see if an element is in the container is O(1) and each insertion is O(1). Doing this for each element in the array is O(n) and then retrieving them again at the end is also O(n), so you end up with a solution that is O(n).

I leave the actual implementation up to you as an exercise.

Comment: A (Linked)HashSet would be more appropriate. And checking if it exists before adding it is useless, since a Set won't add an element that is already present. So it boils down to `new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray()`

Comment: @JBNizet I haven't done Java in a long time (I'm a C# guy). Not aware of the particular container types available. Internally I'm assuming that a (Linked)HashSet has to check if an item is present before adding it anyway.

Comment: Downvoted as it's useless to attempt to answer this question when OP isn't even able to correctly name the language he's supposed to program in - his example call definitely isn't java but might be javascript instead. Please don't attempt to guess what he could mean, wait for OP to clarify his question. I also doubt OP would be able to understand an answer like yours given his obvious lack of basic programming knowledge; the efficiency part probably went right over his head.

Comment: @l4mpi Fair enough. I wanted to give a general solution so that he could try it himself and maybe learn something while attempting it.